# how to display the result of a procedure running from the server side in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to automate a daily monitoring activity where there are set of scripts to be executed(all are select statements). I am in the process of creating a procedure which runs these scripts and by means of scheduler, this will be running daily once. My problem is since these activities are taking place in server side(server backbone), How do i save the results? Earlier we will run all the scripts manually and save it in a notepad. Is there any option to do the same in automation? Like saving in our PC or SQL developer? Instead of logging in to server and searching the path where the file is saved? I thought of saving the results in a table but i am looking for a better option.Please suggest...

Comment: Saving the results in a table is a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is a good idea to save the results in a table as this gives you flexibility when querying the results or exporting them in multiple formats.

There are multiple options to get the data to the client:

1. Query the table with the results from the client
2. Generate a HTML from the results table and have make it accessible from a HTTP server.
   You can also create a web PL/SQL package and generate the HTML within (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_web.htm#i1006207)
3. Export the data from the results table to a file and put it in a shared directory that is accessible by the client.
4. Email the results from the PL/SQL package.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Will make use of it. However, I am afraid if this involves Java coding because I am yet to learn Java.

Comment: No Java needed. Just PL/SQL. Basically you "print" HTML from PL/SQL. The DBA only has to configure it once so that Apache can access it: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/portal.1111/e12041/using.htm

Comment: @becky: You can also use Oracle Application Express which should be bundled with the database (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/index.html)

Comment: I guess Oracle APEX will do the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought of saving the results in a table but i am looking for a better option.

What is exactly the issue with the "table" option?

Regarding "saving in our PC or SQL developer": one problem with that is that a PC/app screen is:

1. a PC is usually less resilient to reboots, crashes, etc.
2. it's intended for private use. Unless you're working alone - these logs may be of interest to other people;
   ..

Other options: it can be made to send e-mail; copy the file to a well known place (incl. one which is directly mounted on your PC); write to database table (as already suggested); and more.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your suggestion. Sending through e-mail seems a good idea but is it possible to send the entire output in a mail? Or is there any way to send the output as an attachment? I am a beginner as a SQL developer, it would be great if suggest what concept can be used to achieve the same...

Comment: I don't see a problem for sending whole output as e-mail body. There is also some built-in (in Oracle db) support for sending e-mails with attachments: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/A_7749-How-to-send-email-attachments-with-Oracle.html